# Using Javascript to drag-and-drop an image into an unordered list

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop

So, I've been warned that some of my past questions have not been well-received, and I'm in danger of being blocked from asking any more. I hope that this question is well-received and that it doesn't result in me being blocked from asking more questions!  I'll do my very best to formulate it as a clear and useful question.

What I'm trying to do is create javascript to click-and-drag images into nested  lists.  I've read [HTML Drag and Drop between multiple Unordered Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636135/html-drag-and-drop-between-multiple-unordered-lists) and [How to drag and drop into an html unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894152/how-to-drag-and-drop-into-an-html-unordered-list), and neither addresses what I'm trying to do.

The images I want to click-and-drag represent items--some items can contain other items while others cannot.  For instance, a Single-Barrel Shotgun can contain Shotgun Ammo, but Shotgun Ammo cannot contain anything.

I've created a jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/pjamesnorris25/9f0y8edz/76/, to facilitate some javascript wizard helping me with this.  And because I have, I'm not going to post the javascript here unless someone asks me to do so.

My javascript works if you click-and-drag the shotgun to the "Left Shoulder"  in the image of the generic person below the "Shotgun Ammo" and "Single-Barrel Shotgun" images in the upper right-hand corner.  That is, when you do so, the text "Single Barrel Shotgun" appears below the "Left Shoulder"  in a  of its own denoted by a box around the text--the box indicates that "Single Barrel Shotgun" is a container into which you can drag other items, in this case, "Shotgun Ammo".

Prior to dragging the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" graphic to the "Left Shoulder" container, my HTML looks like this:

```
<span id="leftshoulder-span" style="border:black solid 1px; left:387px; height:30px; width:173px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:96px; " ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
<ul id="leftshoulder-ul" style="left:387px; position:absolute; top:126px; z-index:101; "></ul>
```

After dragging the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" to the "Left Shoulder", the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="leftshoulder-ul" style="left:387px; position:absolute; top:126px; z-index:101; ">
  <li id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-li" style="margin-top:2px;">
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="tooltip">
        Single Barrel Shotgun
        <span class="tooltipimage">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sGCvntKs/Single-Barrel-Shotgun.gif" id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1" class="zoom_small card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-contents-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
    <ul id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-ul"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Which is exactly what I want.  But when I drag the "Shotgun Ammo" image to the "Single Barrel Shotgun" text , I get:

```
<ul id="leftshoulder-ul" style="left:387px; position:absolute; top:126px; z-index:101; ">
  <li id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-li" style="margin-top:2px;">
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="tooltip">
        Single Barrel Shotgun
        <span class="tooltipimage">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sGCvntKs/Single-Barrel-Shotgun.gif" id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1" class="zoom_small card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
    <img id="Shotgun_Shell_4" class="zoom_small card" src="https://i.postimg.cc/N28LZpPT/Shotgun-Shell.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-contents-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
    <ul id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-ul">
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that the `<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sGCvntKs/Single-Barrel-Shotgun.gif" ...` is after the `</span>` closing the `<span class="tooltipimage">` and not in an `<li>` inside `<ul id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-ul"></ul>`.

That is, what I want is:

```
<ul id="leftshoulder-ul" style="left:387px; position:absolute; top:126px; z-index:101; ">
  <li id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-li" style="margin-top:2px;">
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div class="tooltip">
        Single Barrel Shotgun
        <span class="tooltipimage">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sGCvntKs/Single-Barrel-Shotgun.gif" id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1" class="zoom_small card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-contents-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
    <ul id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-ul">
      <li id="Shotgun_Shell_4-li" style="margin-top:2px;">
      <div class="tooltip">
        Shotgun Shell
        <span class="tooltipimage">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sGCvntKs/Shotgun-Shell.gif" id="Shotgun_Shell_4" class="zoom_small card">
        </span>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What's got me flabbergasted is that the javascript that properly places the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" as an unordered list item under the "Left Shoulder" doesn't place the "Shotgun Shell" as an unordered list item under the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" when the HTML for the two has exactly the same structure.  That is, the "Left Shoulder" has a uniquely `id`'d `<span>` followed by a uniquely `id`'d `<ul>`:

```
<span id="leftshoulder-span" style="border:black solid 1px; left:387px; height:30px; width:173px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:96px; " ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
<ul id="leftshoulder-ul" style="left:387px; position:absolute; top:126px; z-index:101; "></ul>
```

and the "Single Barrel Shotgun" also has a uniquely `id`'d  followed by a uniquely `id`'d :

```
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-contents-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></span>
    <ul id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-ul"></ul>
```

I have built in some error checking alerts--that don't work in jsfiddle for some reason; extra bonus point to anyone who can explain this to me.  When I run the code on my machine, I get the following when I first click-and-drag the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" to the "Left Shoulder":

[image: error checking for dragging the Shotgun]

which tells me that the javascript is correctly identifying the `<span>` to which the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" is being dragged, *i.e.*, the `leftshoulder-span`, the code knows the `id` of the "Single-Barrel Shotgun" being dropped into the `leftshoulder` `<ul>` is "Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1" (the "_1" indicates that this is the first of the "Single-Barrel Shotgun"'s that can be dragged, and that the item is a "Single Barrel Shotgun".

But when I click-and-drag the "Shotgun Ammo", the error checking alert I get is:

[image: error checking for dragging the Shotgun Ammo]

which, because the `eve.target.id` tells me that the code doesn't recognize that it should be putting the "Shotgun Ammo" as the first `<li>` in the `<ul id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-ul">`.

So my question is:  how do I modify my javascript so that when I click-and-drag the "Shotgun Ammo" to the "Single Barrel Shotgun" it appears as an unordered list item under the "Single Barrel Shotgun"?  Or put differently, why is `eve.target.id` in my error checking alert blank when I click-and-drag the "Shotgun Ammo" to the "Single Barrel Shotgun"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct here, but I think the reason my javascript wasn't working was that it was looking for the `id` for the inner-most `span` to which I was trying to drag the "Shotgun Shell", *i.e.*:

`<span class="tooltipimage">`

for which there was no `id`.

So, I wrote my javascript to add an `id` to every `div` and `span` daughter of `id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-span"` like so:

```
    <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-span" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="border:1px solid black;">
      <div id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-tooltip" class="tooltip">
        Single Barrel Shotgun
        <span id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1-tooltipimage" class="tooltipimage">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sGCvntKs/Single-Barrel-Shotgun.gif" id="Single_Barrel_Shotgun_1" class="zoom_small card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </span>
      </div>
    </span>
```

And, lo and behold, the "Shotgun Shell" now appears as an unordered list item under the "Shotgun" the way I want it to.

The javascript that does the trick is:

```
        function addContentsSpan(str_possession)
        {
            var str_item = str_possession.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").replace(/_/g, " ").slice(0, -(" ".length));
            var str_possession_li = str_possession + "-li";
            var str_possession_span = str_possession + "-span";

            var ele_span = document.getElementById(str_possession_span);
            ele_span.setAttribute("id", str_possession_span);
            ele_span.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)");
            ele_span.setAttribute("ondragover", "allowDrop(event)");
            ele_span.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid black;");
            var ele_li = document.getElementById(str_possession_li);

            var ele_ul = document.createElement("ul");
            ele_ul.setAttribute("id", (str_possession + "-ul"));
            ele_li.appendChild(ele_ul);
            
        } // function addContentsSpan(str_possession_li)

        function allowDrop(eve) { eve.preventDefault(); }
        
        function drag(eve) 
        { 
            eve.dataTransfer.setData("text", eve.target.id);
            console.log(eve.target.id);
        }
        
        function drop(eve) 
        {
            bool_debug = false;

            // identify the item being moved
            var str_possession = eve.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            var str_container = eve.dataTransfer.setData("text", eve.target.id);
            var str_item = str_possession.replace(/_/g, " ").replace(/[0-9]/g, "").slice(0, -(" ".length));
                
            // drop the item in the container           
            if (eve.target.id.slice(-("-tooltip").length) == "-tooltip") { eve.target.id = eve.target.id.slice(0, -("-tooltip").length) + "-span"; }

            var str_item_parent = eve.target.id.slice(0, -("-span").length) + "-ul";
            
            var str_location = eve.target.id.slice(0, -("-span").length) + "-ul";
            var ele_location = document.getElementById(str_location);

            eve.preventDefault();
            eve.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(str_possession));

            var ele_li = document.createElement("li");
            ele_li.setAttribute("id", (str_possession + "-li"));
            ele_li.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:2px;");
            ele_location.appendChild(ele_li);

            var ele_divTooltip = document.createElement("div");
            ele_divTooltip.setAttribute("class", "tooltip");
            ele_divTooltip.setAttribute("id", (str_possession + "-tooltip"));

            var ele_spanDrop = document.createElement("span");
            ele_spanDrop.setAttribute("id", (str_possession + "-span"));
            ele_li.appendChild(ele_spanDrop);

            ele_divTooltip.textContent = str_item;
            ele_spanDrop.appendChild(ele_divTooltip);

            var ele_spanTooltipImage = document.createElement("span");
            ele_spanTooltipImage.setAttribute("id", str_possession + "-tooltipimage");
            ele_spanTooltipImage.setAttribute("class", "tooltipimage");
            ele_divTooltip.appendChild(ele_spanTooltipImage);

            var ele_image = document.createElement("img");
            ele_image.setAttribute("src", ("img/cards/items/" + str_item + ".gif"));
            ele_image.setAttribute("id", str_possession);
            ele_image.setAttribute("class", "zoom_small card");
            ele_image.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            ele_image.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
            ele_spanTooltipImage.appendChild(ele_image);
            
            // remove the item from "Possessions"
            document.getElementById(str_possession).remove()
            
            // remove item from previous container
            if (bool_debug) { alert("line " + 1366 + ":\n" + "str_item_parent = " + str_item_parent + "\n" + "possession list element = " + str_possession + "-li"); }
            if (str_item_parent.slice(-("-ul")) == "-ul") { document.getElementById(str_item_parent).removeChild(str_possession + "-li"); }
                        
            // update the Solo_Possession table with the new item
            str_target_id = eve.target.id;
            if (bool_debug) { alert("line " + 1371 +": str_target_id = \"" + str_target_id + "\"\n" + "str_possession = " + str_possession); }
            
            insertItem(str_possession);
            
            if (arr_space[str_item]['space'] > 0) { addContentsSpan(str_possession); }
            
            eve.dataTransfer.clearData();
                    
        } // function drop(eve)
```